# I need to acces a file (excel, txt) from onedrive

Tags: c#

So until now I was testing the application using a local path to find the file that I try to work with

```cs
string path = @"A:\Log\OLP_Application_Storage\call.bat";
try
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "call.bat";
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"A:\Log\OLP_Application_Storage\call.bat";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "call.bat";
    process.Start();
}
```

I have a bat file that calls a python script, with this path is working like a charm. The thing is that I try my app to be used by multiple users (the ones that have acces to my onedrive) so I need to use the share link from onedrive, I dont know how to addapt it, only replacing the path with the link it does not work.

```cs
string path = https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/userid/ewaaiwjfafjwiajawfiaf";
try
{
    //string pth;
    //pth = "A:\Log\OLP_Application_Storage\call.bat";
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "call.bat";
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/userid/ewaaiwjfafjwiajawfiaf";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "call.bat";
    process.Start();

}
```

I tried something like this but is not working.
Thank you for your time!

Edit: I am not very good at exprimation so it may be confusing.
I use a txt file as a list of ids of users, I use an excel file to store some data when a user uses the app, he insert in couple of spaces, he press send and the app saves it inside excel file. I did all the code on local, but now I want to share the app inside the company. To be able to write mutiple users at the same time inside the excel file, it has to be inside Onedrive. So now I have to find out how to get to it for me to use it (The difference should be seen in the 2 codes example). Thank again for the wasted time! It may be a easy problem but I am new to the app production world...

Comment: I will try them all today. Thank you!

Comment: Having read your edit, it sounds like you're actually trying to programmatically access a file on OneDrive from C#. Is that correct? How does this tie into the process code above?

Comment: @Llama Yes is correct, I want to do all programatically. Dont get the second question.

Comment: I mean I don't understand how accessing a file on OneDrive relates to launching call.bat.

Comment: Oh, so I have on Onedrive a folder that contains the files that helps my app, the excel file, the txt file, a python script that modify some things inside the excel file, and a call.bat that I call with the app to start the python script. My app will be distributed to my colleges, and everyone should have acces to my onedrive where this mentioned files are stored and that help the app to do the job.

Comment: Oh. So your C# code should obtain the file from OneDrive and then put it in a folder that your call.bat script can access?

Comment: ```private void Excel_Data_Saving(string dateOV, string boxtxt, string usernm, double hourOV)
        {
            string path = "the link";
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = false;                                                                              
            ..... etc```

Comment: Anyway, I think the issue is that you're setting your working directory to an HTTP URI. I don't know about OneDrive, but I know similar tools have traditionally synced the data to a folder on your computer. You could try starting there to see if such a local folder exists. If that's not possible, and you need to be logged in to see the file, you might need to use the OneDrive API. Otherwise, you could maybe try and download it using `HttpClient`. Basically the goal is to set the working directory to a directory on your computer.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you can just pass the HTTP URI for the file to Excel (I imagine it has all the necessary tie-ins with OneDrive. Sorry, I'm not very experienced in this area) and have Excel open it.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but aparently not.. Thank anyway, I will try linking the app to the folder as in the links above. When I will get to the solution I will post it here!